# Replace empty/NULL result by "FALSE" in the result of SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to know if it is possible to replace the result of a SELECT by the string "FALSE", when a value returned empty or null? Thank you

Comment: Hint : `NVL/COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use case when

```
select case when COL_NAME is null  OR LENGTH(TRIM (COL_NAME)) = 0 then 'False' 
           else COL_NAME end
       from table_name
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I see that it works with one column, but I'm having 6 columns in my SELECT, and I need to do it for each one.

Comment: How many cases when Oracle function length for varchar2 returns 0 do you know?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for COALESCE.

```
SELECT COALESCE(COL_NAME, 'False') AS COL_NAME FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT CASE WHEN 
            COLUMN IS NULL OR COLUMN '' THEN 'FALSE' 
            ELSE COLUMN 
            END
       FROM TABLE_NAME`